# Knockout foreach doesn't work in a .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, knockout.js

I am beginner with Knockout and I need some help.
I have a HTML structure with text-bindings and a content.js file here:         http://jsfiddle.net/Hplatini89/aszsh3bb/
HTML:

```
<div class="testimonials  light-paper-pattern">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3  hidden-xs">
                <div class="testimonials__quotes">
                    <img alt="#" class="testimonials__quotes--img" src="templates/images/quotes.png" width="224" height="175">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12  col-sm-6">
                <a href="#js--testimonails-carousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-circle  glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                <h4 class="testimonials__title"><span class="light" data-bind="text: sTitle_light" ></span><span data-bind="text: sTitle_dark" ></span></h4>
                <a href="#js--testimonails-carousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon  glyphicon-circle  glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
                <hr class="divider-dark">
                <div id="js--testimonails-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="5000">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item" data-bind="foreach: aoItem">
                            <q class="testimonials__text"><span data-bind="text: aoItem.sLine1"></span><br>
                                <span data-bind="text: aoItem.sLine2"></span>
                            </q><br><br>
                            <cite><b data-bind="text: aoItem.sName"></b></cite> <span data-bind="text: aoItem.sPosition"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3  hidden-xs">
                <div class="testimonials__quotes--rotate">
                    <img alt="#" class="testimonials__quotes--img" src="templates/images/quotes.png" width="224" height="175">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

content.js:

```
function Testimonials() {

    var self = this;

    self.sTitle_dark = "About Us";
    self.sTitle_light = "Others ";

    self.aoItem = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.aoItem = [
        {
            sLine1: "A top quality product delivered super quick! Thank you so much Organic Shop,",
            sLine2: "I shall definitely be using you guys again!",
            sName: "John Don Joe, ",
            sPosition: "Musician"
        },
        {
            sLine1: "A top quality product delivered super quick! Thank you so much Organic Shop,",
            sLine2: "I shall definitely be using you guys again!",
            sName: "John Don Joe, ",
            sPosition: "Musician"
        },
        {
            sLine1: "A top quality product delivered super quick! Thank you so much Organic Shop,",
            sLine2: "I shall definitely be using you guys again!",
            sName: "John Don Joe, ",
            sPosition: "Musician"
        }
    ];
    /*var length = aoCards.length;
    var index = self.aoCards.indexOf()+5;
    self.cssClassitems = "ca-item-" + index;*/



}
ko.applyBindings(new Testimonials());
```

Simple text-binding is working, only foreach wouldn't.
My code with foreach is working in a .html file, but won't work in a .php file.

I tried to include the .html file in php and I tried to use .tpl file too.

Please help me with any clue.

Thank you in advance,
András

Comment: You create an observableArray and then you override it to a simple array,